# Bootstrap navbar (left menu) not aligned properly at top

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have problems with left navigation bar positioning. If you run the snipped below on fullscreen and try to resize browser you will see that left navigation bar is not fixed to the top of page.

Also I header (logo and dropdowns) does not covers full page.

Maybe I missed something?

Any help will be highly appreciated!

Thanks, who wasted time to view this post and helped to dummy :)

```js
    function htmlbodyHeightUpdate(){
  var height3 = $( window ).height()
  var height1 = $('.nav').height()+50
  height2 = $('.main').height()
  if(height2 > height3){
   $('html').height(Math.max(height1,height3,height2)+10);
   $('body').height(Math.max(height1,height3,height2)+10);
  }
  else
  {
   $('html').height(Math.max(height1,height3,height2));
   $('body').height(Math.max(height1,height3,height2));
  }
  
 }
 $(document).ready(function () {
  htmlbodyHeightUpdate()
  $( window ).resize(function() {
   htmlbodyHeightUpdate()
  });
  $( window ).scroll(function() {
   height2 = $('.main').height()
     htmlbodyHeightUpdate()
  });
 });
```

```css
   header.navbar+nav.navbar{
   /* margin-top: 20px;same margin-bottom .navbar */
   }
   .navbar.navbar-default.navbar-fixed-top{
   margin-top: 50px;
   }
   .sidebar.navbar-fixed-top{
    margin-top: 100px;
   }

   @media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 998px){
       .navbar.navbar-default.navbar-fixed-top{
       margin-top: 100px;
       }
       .sidebar.navbar-fixed-top{
        margin-top: 150px;
       }
    }

  /* Custom navbar default: global*/

  .navbar.navbar-default{
    background-color: #f8f8f8;
    border-color: #e7e7e7;
    margin: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
  }
  .navbar.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
    color: #666;
    text-shadow: none;
    min-width: 150px;
    }
   .navbar.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
    color: #666;
    text-shadow: none;
    }
    .navbar.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
    color: #666;
    text-shadow: none;
    }
    .navbar.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover{
    color: #acc47f;
    }
    .navbar.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a{
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #acc47f;
    }
    .navbar.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover{
    color: #608224;
    background-color: #acc47f;
    }
    .navbar.navbar-default .caret {
    border-top-color: #ccc;
    border-bottom-color: #ccc;
    }
    .navbar.navbar-default .caret:hover {
    border-top-color: #333;
    border-bottom-color: #333;
    }


/* Custom sidebar menu */

 /*Remove rounded coners*/

  nav.sidebar.navbar {
    border-radius: 0px;
  }

  nav.sidebar, .main{
    -webkit-transition: margin 200ms ease-out;
      -moz-transition: margin 200ms ease-out;
      -o-transition: margin 200ms ease-out;
      transition: margin 200ms ease-out;
  }

  /* Add gap to nav and right windows.*/
  .main{
    padding: 10px 10px 0 10px;
  }

  /* .....NavBar: Icon only with coloring/layout.....*/

  /*small/medium side display*/
  @media (min-width: 768px) {

    /*Allow main to be next to Nav*/
    .main{
      position: absolute;
      width: calc(100% - 40px); /*keeps 100% minus nav size*/
      margin-left: 40px;
      float: right;
    }

    /*lets nav bar to be showed on mouseover*/
    nav.sidebar:hover + .main{
      margin-left: 200px;
    }

    /*Center Brand*/
    nav.sidebar.navbar.sidebar>.container .navbar-brand, .navbar>.container-fluid .navbar-brand {
      margin-left: 0px;
    }
    /*Center Brand*/
    nav.sidebar .navbar-brand, nav.sidebar .navbar-header{
      text-align: center;
      width: 100%;
      margin-left: 0px;
    }

    /*Center Icons*/
    nav.sidebar a{
      padding-right: 13px;
            min-width: 100px;
    }

    /*custom sidebar nav*/
        nav.sidebar ul.nav.navbar-nav{
            margin: 0;
        }
        nav.sidebar.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>li>a {
            color: white;
        }

    /*adds border top to first nav box */
    nav.sidebar .navbar-nav > li:first-child{
      border-top: 1px #e5e5e5 solid;
    }

    /*adds border to bottom nav boxes*/
    nav.sidebar .navbar-nav > li{
      border-bottom: 1px #e5e5e5 solid;
    }
    /*adds background on hover*/
    nav.sidebar .navbar-nav > li:hover{
        color: #fff;
            background-color: #43600E;
    }
    /*removes border last element*/
    nav.sidebar .navbar-nav > li.last{
      border-bottom: none;
    }

    /* Colors/style dropdown box*/
    nav.sidebar .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu {
      position: static;
      float: none;
      width: auto;
      margin-top: 0;
      background-color: transparent;
      border: 0;
      -webkit-box-shadow: none;
      box-shadow: none;
    }

    /*allows nav box to use 100% width*/
    nav.sidebar .navbar-collapse, nav.sidebar .container-fluid{
      padding: 0 0px 0 0px;
    }

    /*colors dropdown box text */
    .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>li>a {
      color: #777;
    }

/*O quanto o menu irá esconder á esquerda*/
    /*gives sidebar width/height*/
    nav.sidebar{
      width: 200px;
      height: 100%;
      margin-left: -270px;
      float: left;
      z-index: 8000;
      margin-bottom: 0px;
    }

    /*give sidebar 100% width;*/
    nav.sidebar li {
      width: 100%;
    }

    /* Move nav to full on mouse over*/
    nav.sidebar:hover{
      margin-left: 0px;
    }
    /*for hiden things when navbar hidden*/
    .forAnimate{
      opacity: 0;
    }
  }

  /* .....NavBar: Fully showing nav bar..... */

  @media (min-width: 1330px) {

/*     Allow main to be next to Nav
    .main{
      width: calc(100% - 200px); keeps 100% minus nav size
      margin-left: 200px;
    }

    Show all nav
    nav.sidebar{
      margin-left: 0px;
      float: left;
    }
    Show hidden items on nav
    nav.sidebar .forAnimate{
      opacity: 1;
    } */
  }

  nav.sidebar .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>li>a:hover, nav.sidebar .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>li>a:focus {
    color: #CCC;
    background-color: transparent;
  }

  nav:hover .forAnimate{
    opacity: 1;
  }
  
  
  /*---- FIM SLIDE MENU*/
  
  .nav-side-menu {
  overflow: auto;
  font-family: verdana;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 200;
  background-color: #2e353d;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100%;
  color: #e1ffff;
}
.nav-side-menu .brand {
  background-color: #23282e;
  line-height: 50px;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.nav-side-menu .toggle-btn {
  display: none;
}
.nav-side-menu ul,
.nav-side-menu li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  line-height: 35px;
  cursor: pointer;
  /*    
    .collapsed{
       .arrow:before{
                 font-family: FontAwesome;
                 content: "\f053";
                 display: inline-block;
                 padding-left:10px;
                 padding-right: 10px;
                 vertical-align: middle;
                 float:right;
            }
     }
*/
}
.nav-side-menu ul :not(collapsed) .arrow:before,
.nav-side-menu li :not(collapsed) .arrow:before {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  content: "\f078";
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  float: right;
}
.nav-side-menu ul .active,
.nav-side-menu li .active {
  border-left: 3px solid #d19b3d;
  background-color: #4f5b69;
}
.nav-side-menu ul .sub-menu li.active,
.nav-side-menu li .sub-menu li.active {
  color: #d19b3d;
}
.nav-side-menu ul .sub-menu li.active a,
.nav-side-menu li .sub-menu li.active a {
  color: #d19b3d;
}
.nav-side-menu ul .sub-menu li,
.nav-side-menu li .sub-menu li {
  background-color: #181c20;
  border: none;
  line-height: 28px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #23282e;
  margin-left: 0px;
}
.nav-side-menu ul .sub-menu li:hover,
.nav-side-menu li .sub-menu li:hover {
  background-color: #020203;
}
.nav-side-menu ul .sub-menu li:before,
.nav-side-menu li .sub-menu li:before {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  content: "\f105";
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.nav-side-menu li {
  padding-left: 0px;
  border-left: 3px solid #2e353d;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #23282e;
}
.nav-side-menu li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #e1ffff;
}
.nav-side-menu li a i {
  padding-left: 10px;
  width: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
}
.nav-side-menu li:hover {
  border-left: 3px solid #d19b3d;
  background-color: #4f5b69;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .nav-side-menu {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
  .nav-side-menu .toggle-btn {
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    top: 10px;
    z-index: 10 !important;
    padding: 3px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    color: #000;
    width: 40px;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .brand {
    text-align: left !important;
    font-size: 22px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    line-height: 50px !important;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 767px) {
  .nav-side-menu .menu-list .menu-content {
    display: block;
  }
}
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

nav.navbar-findcond { background: #fff; border-color: #ccc; box-shadow: 0 0 2px 0 #ccc; }
nav.navbar-findcond a { color: #f14444; }
nav.navbar-findcond ul.navbar-nav a { color: #f14444; border-style: solid; border-width: 0 0 2px 0; border-color: #fff; }
nav.navbar-findcond ul.navbar-nav a:hover,
nav.navbar-findcond ul.navbar-nav a:visited,
nav.navbar-findcond ul.navbar-nav a:focus,
nav.navbar-findcond ul.navbar-nav a:active { background: #fff; }
nav.navbar-findcond ul.navbar-nav a:hover { border-color: #f14444; }
nav.navbar-findcond li.divider { background: #ccc; }
nav.navbar-findcond button.navbar-toggle { background: #f14444; border-radius: 2px; }
nav.navbar-findcond button.navbar-toggle:hover { background: #999; }
nav.navbar-findcond button.navbar-toggle > span.icon-bar { background: #fff; }
nav.navbar-findcond ul.dropdown-menu { border: 0; background: #fff; border-radius: 4px; margin: 4px 0; box-shadow: 0 0 4px 0 #ccc; }
nav.navbar-findcond ul.dropdown-menu > li > a { color: #444; }
nav.navbar-findcond ul.dropdown-menu > li > a:hover { background: #f14444; color: #fff; }
nav.navbar-findcond span.badge { background: #f14444; font-weight: normal; font-size: 11px; margin: 0 4px; }
nav.navbar-findcond span.badge.new { background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.8); color: #fff; }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html><head><title>test</title>
 <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="bootstrap.min.css" />
 <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="nabs.css" />
 <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="font-awesome.min.css" />
    </head>
    <body class="sidebar-mini">
<div class="main">
<aside>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse sidebar navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">

 <div class="nav-side-menu">
     <div class="brand">logo</div>
     <i class="fa fa-bars fa-2x toggle-btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#menu-content"></i>
            <div class="menu-list">

  <ul id="menu-content" class="menu-content collapse out">
      <li>
   <a href="#">
       <i class="fa fa-dashboard fa-lg"></i> Dashboard
   </a>
      </li>
      <li  data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#1" class="collapsed">
   <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-gift fa-lg"></i> Processing  </a></li>
   <li  data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#4" class="collapsed"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-gift fa-lg"></i> Payments  </a></li>
   </ul>
      </div>
 </div>
    </nav>
</aside>
<nav class="navbar navbar-findcond navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
  <div class="navbar-header">
   <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Logo</a>
  </div>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar">
   <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li class="dropdown">
     <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-bell-o"></i> Invites <span class="badge">0</span></a>
     <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-tag"></i> new <span class="badge">Video</span> video</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-thumbs-o-up"></i> <span class="badge">Music</span> liked</a></li>
      
     </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Main <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
    <li class="dropdown">
     <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Admin <span class="caret"></span></a>
     <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
      <li><a href="#">test1</a></li>
      <li class="divider"></li>
      <li><a href="#">test2</a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </div>
</nav>








<section class="content-header">
    <h1>
 <small>hi</small>
    </h1>
    <ol class="breadcrumb">
 <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> Home</a></li>
 <li class="active">Dashboard</li>
    </ol>
</section><section class="content">
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-12">
 hi there</div></div>
</section>
<table border="0" style="border: 1px; border-style: dotted;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%">
    <tr bgcolor="#D5E7F7">
 <td width="100%">

 </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The black navbar has a sidebar class seems to break the functionality of the navbar.

PS: fixing this will cause the black navbar to fix to the top of the screen and be overlayed by the white navbar, if you want the black one to have precedent you'll need to up its z-index.

Comment: Tried but no success :(

Comment: Then you will have to provide more information, because im not sure i'm seeing the same result as you are, Only thing that was out of place was the black nav on  screens 768px or less. Could you take a screenshot ilustrating the problem? Also what browser are you seeing this error in?